# What are the uses of bones from the different animals bred industrially?

Tags: waste, animals, waste-minimisation, biodegradable-waste

The food industry grows animals for meat, but some parts cannot be sold for human consumption.

What is the final use of bones from the different animals grown industrially? pigs, beef, poultry etc.

Comment: Some is processed into fertilizer ( primarily phosphorus ).

Comment: Ever wondered what gelatin is made of? Right, bones (and skin).

Comment: [Blood & bone fertilizer](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/blood-bone-fertilizer-44632.html).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of it is ground up and used as animal feed. for the same animals...

Comment: Thanks for the answer; please consider [improving it](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) by adding sources. You might also want to list more uses (some examples are given in the comments above).